# Real world applications of partial metric

Tags: applications, iterated-function-system

What are the real-world applications of the partial metric notion introduced by Steve G Matthews? I am writing a paper connecting partial metric with iterated function systems and trying to find the plausible applications.

**Edit:**
The theoretical aspects are in https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/pmetric/Ma94.pdf and https://www.jstor.org/stable/40391197?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

Comment: Please explain, and/or give a link to some source which explains, the partial metric notion introduced by Steve G. Mattews (note: should the surname be Mathews instead?). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it is Steve G Matthews with an 'h'.